# Homegrown integration system OR ESB?

Tags: .net, architecture, integration, soa, esb

I just recently started working for a small company which is currently experiencing growing pains. I am not sure what kind of system it is that I am about to describe here.  Essentially we have a potpourri of many different 3rd applications which are talking to each other by a homegrown “integration system” which is a mix of SQL jobs, background services written in .NET, FTP transfers, and SSIS etc.

Here is the bird’s eye view:
Our public facing website is an Order Entry System (3rd party Shopping Cart software) hosted offsite by the vendor. We download order information every 4 hours a day. This data then gets massaged by our home grown “integration system” which feeds this information to our Inventory and Warehouse Management System (WMS). It also feeds information to MS Great Plains, Pulse, PayFuse, and third party CMS etc.

As you may have already guessed this architecture is very fragile and a slight mishap (such as FTP failure of SQL job failure) may cause discrepancy in data can have a domino effect. There have been times when due to data related issues or replication issues may cause the whole warehouse to come to stand still and we at times are unable to take orders, process, or ship orders.

My task is to re-architect our systems and remove the tight coupling of the systems to allow business growth. What areas do I need to look into? I have been researching ESB and SOA but am being told that my company cannot afford a half a million dollar undertaking to go with say iWay or Talend.

What options are there? Is in-house development the answer and is it cheaper than ESB implementation? Has anyone gone through similar growing pains and if so how did you handle the integration?

Comment: First off: the following software has been developed by myself (mostly) --- you can try my FOSS project Shuttle (https://shuttle.codeplex.com/).  In a hosting environment you could run your queues off sql server tables.  It is running in production at a large international insurance firm and one of the large four banks in South Africa.  May be used elsewhere also but I would not be aware of that.  Give it a go and please do let me know what you think should you take a look.

Answer (score 7):

Here's how I would approach this problem.

1. Forget about up front design of a single "perfect" system.
2. Forget about replacing everything all at once.
3. Find something that causes a lot of pain, is relatively easy to replace, and doesn't threaten the existence of the business. Work on that first.

In some ways, the fact that there is a "potpourri of many different 3rd applications" is a good thing. You can leave the better ones in place while concentrating on fixing the ones where there is the most business value.

Seek out your stable business concepts and model those explicitly. Command and Event patterns are your friends here. Group these concepts into "Services" following [SOA](http://www.udidahan.com/2012/12/10/service-oriented-api-implementations/) principles.

From your text, it looks like discussions around SLA have already implicitly begun. Make those SLA discussions explicit, but focus on improvement over time towards a goal rather than overnight transformation.

Hand rolling infrastructure for this transformation is probably not worth the time, but spending 6 or 7 figures on a product before you know where you're going is not wise either. Since you mentioned .Net, I have used [NServiceBus](http://particular.net/nservicebus) and find it to be a pleasant programming experience. You focus on your domain and your business logic and let NSB handle the plumbing/infrastructure. For low message throughput, there is a free option. That allows you to deliver some business value before having a discussion about budget and funding. There is a thriving [NServiceBus community](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/) to help you get started in addition to the documentation on the website.

There are other options in the .net space as well including [MassTransit](http://masstransit-project.com/) and [EventStore](http://geteventstore.com/). I have not personally used these and they are not functionally equivalent, so you'd need to look them over and see what meets your needs and your team's capabilities.

Comment: Great answer IMO. I agree with Kijana's approach. After the first fixes, focus on improving the processes that keep the business running: ie accepting orders, and make sure the system is available and not loosing data. Refine the architecture in small steps, adding value and stability as you go. In my experience, the products Kajina mentioned really help. I'd stay away from expensive broker type products as they tend to only introduce another point of failure and complexity and will cost you a lot of $ before even having solved anything. It's a daunting task that you can't solve all at once.

Comment: I'm working in a project which uses for the java part Talend ESB. Our development team uses .NET and NServiceBus. We developed a custom ActiveMQ transport layer for integrating natively with the Talend solution in several weeks. The community and especially the people around NServiceBus helped us a lot tackling theses problems. The community is the greatest benefit of NServiceBus. I would not try to roll your own because things like managing transactions and more will delay your feature output several months...

Comment: Although I love a community, it's hard to sell something like that. Especially since I fell for it myself with Umbraco. Latest version was supposed to be awesome and support MVC and have a great community. Until the Umbraco Org. decided to ditch that version, as it had a bad architectural design. We almost invested A LOT of money in it. So glad we postponed the project a bit.

Luckely NServiceBus has paid support : http://particular.net/support

Comment: Agree with Kijana, good answer. Try to find components that are at the beginning of end of a process. Sounds like your integration points are good candidates. These are more easily extracted from the big ball of mud, into autonomous components using SOA and EDA.

Answer (score 2):

We've been working through some similar issues over the past couple of years.  Leveraging an ESB will help you chip away at it.  Once teams start to appreciate the decoupling this starts to give you it will accelerate the process.  I'm most familiar with NServiceBus which we've found to have a really low barrier to entry.  Developers pick it up quick and it is low cost to try.  I would agree you want to start with the area that is most critical to the business and get that on solid ground first.